# How do I make mailto links open in my Yahoo Mail in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, email, yahoo-mail, mailto

When I read an email in my Yahoo Mail and click on a mailto: link it tries to open Outlook but since I don't have it installed nothing happens. I would like it to open a reply to the email in Yahoo Mail. How do I set this up. I'm running Windows 7.

Comment: Found the answer by exploring the Control Panel:

Control Panel > Programs > Default Programs > Set Default Programs

In the list that appears on the left of the window click on Google Chrome

Then click on the link "Choose defaults for this program" that appears at the bottom of the window.

In the next window to appear, under the Protocols section click on the MAILTO check-box to select it, then click the save button at lower right.

Comment: I also found this useful... that is if you don't mind installing the yahoo toolbar: http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/yahoomail/settings/settings-10.html

Comment: I prefer to install as few extensions (especially toolbars) as I can as they often surreptitiously install other pernicious "features". The solution I found (which I had to post as a comment due to only having a beginners reputation) reduces the risk of this sort of exploitation IMHO.

Comment: I agree.  The most annoying extensions are the "uncheck the box if you *don't* wish to install the ASK Toolbar" type (sneaky Sun Microsystems).

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer by exploring the Control Panel:

Control Panel > Programs > Default Programs > Set Default Programs.

In the list that appears on the left of the window click on Google Chrome, 
then click on the link "Choose defaults for this program" that appears at the bottom of the window.

In the next window to appear, under the Protocols section click on the MAILTO check-box to select it, then click the save button at lower right.

That's it!